# JQuery - Create, Detach, Clone, AppendTo methodology feasability

Tags: jquery, html

Using standard `JQuery` is there a way to create elements during the initial page load, by simply including them in the `HTML` markup and than `detach` them for later use, then use `eventhandlers` to `clone` a deep copy and `append` it back to the DOM?

I want to use this approach for a multi-sectioned form so that upon an `event` you receive a new copy of an element as it existed prior to the `detach`. My thought is that this will allow me to provide a fresh state (as it originally existed) on-demand and limit the amount of modifications I have to make to the elements as I can just remove copies when they aren't needed anymore.

Unfortunately Google did not turn up much information on this technique and I could not get a detached element to clone last attempt.

I apologize for not including a code snippet in advance.

Comment: start here: http://api.jquery.com/detach/

Comment: and then: http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: Side note: Be cautious when using detach, it can lead to memory leaks if improperly handled.